# How to fix "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'home'"

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

Hi please help me link my home page to my app, every time I run the command "python manage.py runserver" I get the following (attached).

Also my localhost 8000 page is not updating to the changes I'm making in my Atom text editor[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbuf0.png)

Comment: can you describe your directory(web app folder strucutre) it shows you have not home in views.py

Comment: I've edited the question and attached my app directory. desktop/myproject/sixerr/sixerrapp.. inside the app folder (__pycache__+ migrations + templates)

Comment: there is no views.py file so how can you even run it? I would recommend you to read django directory structure . http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/  also please upvote this comment if you find it useful